# Регулярное выражение: разрешить только цифры и пробел

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, .net

Нужно ограничить ввод пользователю, чтобы он мог вводить только цифры или пробельные символы.
Правильность ввода проверяю этим методом:

```
 private bool IsTextAllowed(string text)
 {
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^0-9]|\S");
    return !regex.IsMatch(text);
 }
```

Однако такой код вообще не позволяет вводить символы. Что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу ошибаться, но, по-моему, вот такой паттерн работает:

```
^[0-9 ]+$
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Только с небольшой поправкой:
[^0-9 ]+$

Comment: @Zer0CooL, поправка некорректна. Регулярное выражение соответсвует задаче.  
Как поправка нужно убрать восклицательный знак из return.